# DotNetNuke Action Form HTML

Tags: dotnetnuke

My company's site was built with DNN.  Is there a way you can view the HTML of an action form within the CMS itself?  I need to be able to export the HTML of our forms.

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on the page in your browser and view the HTML that is generated in the browser's VIEW SOURCE option, but that is likely the only option for you without getting into the Code of the module itself to build an export function.